# BroadcastReceiver onReceive for chat function

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to setup a chat function with android studio, but the chat screen is not updating when a message is received.

loadMsg(); function is working when sending message. But not when receiving.

This is code that I have:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    IntentFilter ief = new IntentFilter("test");
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, ief);
}

private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      //  Show("Intent Receved");
        if (intent.getAction().equals("test")) {
            // Do stuff
            loadMsg();
        }
    }
};

public void loadMsg()
{
    ParseUser par=room.getParseUser("unreadBy");
    try{
        par.fetchIfNeeded();
        currentUser.fetchIfNeeded();
    }catch (Exception e){}
    if(par!=null)
    {
        if(par.getObjectId().equals(currentUser.getObjectId()))
        {
            room.put("unread",0);
            room.saveInBackground(null);
        }
    }

    final ParseQuery<ParseObject> msgQ=new ParseQuery("Messages");
    msgQ.whereEqualTo("match",room);
    msgQ.orderByAscending("createdAt");
    msgQ.setLimit(500);
    msgQ.include("user");
    msgQ.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if(e==null) {
                Log.d(tag, "Messges--" + objects.size());
                msgObj = objects;
                if(msgObj.size()>0) {
                    empty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    try {
                        adapter = new AwesomeAdapter(getApplicationContext(), msgObj, currentUser, selfbit, incbit);
                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        lv.setSelection(msgObj.size() - 1);
                    }catch (Exception eg){}
                }

            }else{
                Log.d(tag, "eror--" + e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />                  <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"   android:name="com.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

```
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

   <receiver android:name=".Supported.MyReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <action android:name="com.package.name.UPDATE_STATUS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: Change "com.example.app" to match your app's package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="com.package.name" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: ensure to register / unregister the reciever in onResume / onPause accordingly. If you wish to allow the reciever to get updated when the application is terminated register the reciever in your AndroidManifest

Comment: Perhaps show us the code where you send the broadcast?

Answer (score 1):

Try to changing

```
    if (intent.getAction().equals("test")) {
        // Do stuff
        loadMsg();
    }
```

to

```
    if (intent.getAction().equals("test")) {
        // Do stuff
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                loadMsg();
            }
        });
    }
```